# Docker-compose with automatic lets encrypt ssl

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

Ok Guys, here's my very frustrating problem:

I need to deploy  an mautic Instance With ssl on that. Please note who the SSL needs to be generated automatically, I want a full docker process.

I tried everything, but aparenty  do not exists any slution who generate SSL directly on docker, everything I found uses the server level.

The most  aproximated solution  who I found is using ftraefik, but it will givinf conflict with mautic.

Here's  my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik"
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.email=${SSL_EMAIL}"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_FOLDER}/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      
  mauticdb:
    restart: always
    image: percona/percona-server:5.7
    container_name: mauticdb
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MAUTIC_DB_PASSWORD}
    command:
      --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci

  mautic:
    restart: always
    image: mautic/mautic:latest
    container_name: mautic
    links:
      - mauticdb:mysql
    depends_on:
      - mauticdb
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:80:80
    volumes:
      - mautic_data:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MAUTIC_DB_HOST=mauticdb
      - MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP=3306
      - MAUTIC_DB_USER=root
      - MAUTIC_DB_PASSWORD=${MAUTIC_DB_PASSWORD}
      - MAUTIC_DB_NAME=mautic
      - MAUTIC_RUN_CRON_JOBS=true
      - PHP_INI_DATE_TIMEZONE=${GENERIC_TIMEZONE}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true 
      # Routes
      - traefik.http.routers.mautic.rule=Host(`${MAUTIC_SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN_NAME}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.mautic-secure.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.mautic.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.mautic.tls.certresolver=mytlschallenge
      # Middlewares
      - traefik.http.middlewares.mautic.headers.SSLRedirect=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.mautic.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.mautic.headers.SSLHost=${DOMAIN_NAME}
      - traefik.http.middlewares.mautic.headers.forceSTSHeader=true
       
volumes:
  mautic_data:
  sslcerts:
  mysql_data:
```

Traefik was conflicting with Mautic on port 80. So this'nt workig at all.

Q: How I can  install Traefik and use it  to proxy the Mautic requests  over HTTPS?

And:

If Traefik was not a correct way, what configuration I need to automatically  generate lets encrypt based in a domain feeled in a .env file?

In open to anything  who works.

Thank you;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run MAUTIC on a different port than 80 (as this is used by Traefik)

```
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

You can also configure Traefik to listen on port 443 only: in this case it will only accept HTTPS requests and MAUTIC can run on port 80 without conflicting.

Comment: Sorry, but,  if Mautic only listens on port 80, how I can pass SSL from  traefik to Mautic?

Comment: You can remove `--entrypoints.web.address=:80"` and related port 80 config from Traefik, so it only accept HTTPS. BTW even if Mautic runs on 80 only you are able to map its port 80 to another port so the Mautic container exposes the port you want (ie 8081)

Comment: Sorry Beppe, i'm Really confused.   If mautic listens on port 80 and Traefik on port 443, traefik never will intercept the mauti  requests. And when it made, Mautic never goes to https. I deployed  the docker with your sugestions, but not work at all.

Comment: Traefik listens on 443 and it sits in front of Mautic: when you have a request (https://mymautic....) is proxied to Mautic.

Here is a blog post explaining the process (proxying to another app): https://medium.com/geekculture/from-nginx-to-traefik-with-docker-on-digitalocean-fcaeea3c6a4e

Comment: which URL do you invoke? do you get an error? Check with `docker logs` to see what each container does

Comment: Hi Beppe, no errors reported. I just have the following. a) an mautic installed at mkt.autotic.com.br. b) an traefik instance pointed to 443 port as you said. c) If I try to access mkt.autotic.com.br:443 or https://mkt.autotic.com.br, them I get the 404 error. If I try to use port 80, it work.

Comment: I can see the login page with HTTPS, maybe it has now generated the required SSL certificates

Comment: Ah, sorry. I created a pýthon script to setup nginx as a reversy proxy. Unfortunatelly I do not have time to expend on that. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: ok, good luck. If you are interested I wrote a Medium blog on how to configure Traefik, maybe you spot something useful: https://medium.com/geekculture/from-nginx-to-traefik-with-docker-on-digitalocean-fcaeea3c6a4e